# C# array of pointers

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am currently trying to create an octree in Unity. I would like each node to have a list of pointers that point to the AABB's of the childnodes. The AABB's are a struct that looks like this:

```
    public struct ABB
    {
        public float size;

        public float centerX;
        public float centerY;
        public float centerZ;

        public ABB(float size, float centerX, float centerY, float centerZ)
        {
            this.size = size;
            
            this.centerX = centerX;
            this.centerY = centerY;
            this.centerZ = centerZ;
        }
    }
```

Each node contains a list of its children:

> ```
> public OctreeNode[] children = null;
> ```

I would like to use the AABB's of the children of the node in a bursted job, but the OctreeNodes themselves are a class, which is not supported by burst. Therefore, I would like to get the AABB's, but storing a copy of them for each node seems a bit redundant. Therefore, storing a pointer to the AABB's of the children seems like the best solution for me. However, I fail to understand how to do this in C#.

Currently, I have an array of pointers

> ```
> public ABB*[] childBounds = null;
> ```

My question is, how do I fill this array with pointers?

Something like:

```
    if (children[0] == null)
    {
        children[0] = new OctreeNode(new ABB(childLength, nodeBounds.centerX + -quarter, nodeBounds.centerY + quarter, nodeBounds.centerZ + -quarter), this, rootSeed);
        childBounds[0] = children[0].nodeBounds;
    }
```

Gives me an error, essentially saying that

> Cannot implicitly convert type AABB (children[0].nodeBounds) to AABB*

Could someone try to explain how to do this properly in C#?

Comment: Why is this tagged C? This looks like only C# code. In addition, pointers in C# is not a novice topic. What is `nodeBounds`, and why do you want to deal with pointers in the first place?

Comment: @ gunr2171 my apologies for the C tag, I did not notice it. @MongZhu Yes, burst is indeed a unity thing, the link you referred to is correct. It is not so important for my question though but I thought it would be best to describe what I am doing

Comment: Use the `&` operator to get the address: `childBounds[0] = &children[0].nodeBounds;`. See [Pointer related operators (C# reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/pointer-related-operators). But note that code using these operators is unsafe.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes thanks, this however results in an error, saying that I can't take the adress of an unfixed expression inside of a fixed statement. This probably relates to the 'fixed()' expression, but im not sure where to put it

Comment: If you are going to be using pointers, you need to have a very good understanding of `fixed`, `pinned` and their friends, otherwise you will be working in the last of _bad things happen_ take time to read up on unsafe code. Also, you may want to revisit the premise of your question (for example, do you know all the things that can go wrong when you use a struct?)

Comment: @Flydog57 No, I do not know what can go wrong when I use a struct. Could you meaby point me to some more info on the topic?

Comment: Start by reviewing @ericlippert's blog articles on _value types_ https://ericlippert.com/category/value-types/

Comment: @Flydog57 Thanks! seems like a great article

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone in the comments who pointed me in the right direction.

Essentially, store the pointer in a temporary variable, and then assigned it in a fixed() statement, like so:

```
        fixed(ABB* boundsPtr = &children[0].nodeBounds)
        {
            childBounds[0] = boundsPtr;
        }
```